# Problems with CMenu::ModifyMenu

Tags: c++, mfc, localization, internationalization

I'm using **CMenu::ModifyMenu** in the **OnCreate** method of my **CFrameWnd** derived class to change the captions on my menu to match the user language.

I'm using VC++ designer and the menu is declared in a .rc file.

For the MENUITEM elements I use it as follow:

```
m_wndMenu->ModifyMenu(ID_APP_EXIT, MF_BYCOMMAND, NULL, CString((LPWSTR) ID_APP_EXIT));
```

For the POPUP elements (that don't have an ID) I use it as follow:

```
m_wndMenu->ModifyMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, NULL, CString((LPWSTR) ID_MENU_POPUP_FILE));
```

It works as expected to change the captions, but for the menu items that are initialy disabled when I change the caption they get enabled. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to explicitly disable the menu item and set tool tip text after a call to `ModifyMenu`. Using `ModifyMenu` will effectively destroy the previous menu item and create a new one. You are losing any settings and initialization from the resource file or otherwise that you had on the previous item or menu.

See remarks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tbfebs6(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I changed the code to use SetMenuItemInfo with MMIM_STRING flag set and now the disabled items don't get enabled.

Comment: Yup that would do it as you would merely be updating the string without removing or inserting new menu items. Keep in mind thought string has changed the menu id and subsequently the ON_COMMAND handler for the menu option will be the same. However you can also use `SetMenuItemInfo` to change ids and other menu item attributes as well.

Answer (score 0):

for such scenario, better to use EnableMenuItem function, like this
m_wndMenu->EnableMenuItem(ID_APP_EXIT, MF_BYCOMMAND| MF_ENABLED);

this will work...